# Automatic mesh Aggregation/Merging/Alignment

Tags: c++, matlab, mesh, meshlab

I am looking for an "automatic" mesh merging software/toolbox available open source. I build meshes from point clouds using [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/). I can also use Meshlab for mesh alignment but the problem is it is interactive and I have to choose points from meshes. Any suggestions for automatic mesh aggregation? My ultimate goal is to make this Real time.

P.S. Merging point clouds also works.

Comment: Iterative Closest Point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration

Comment: Those are for aligning meshes. How about mergign/aggregating meshes? Say I am recording images from a stereo camera system mounted on an AUV/ROV for 2 hours. So I have different scenes. I am sure ICP/registration will fail because I have new points every few frames.

Comment: ICP would be used for inter-frame registration. It will get you a rigid affine between frames which you can just multiply together to put it back. (Personally, I would register to the past X frames and get the average measurement to try and make it more accurate.) The errors will build up over time, however. SLAM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) is a very hard, not entirely solved problem.

Comment: So if I have aligned point clouds out of SLAM, Then all I need to do is to "Glue" them in Meshlab for example, and then flatten visible meshes and make a single mesh using "Poisson Surface Reconstruction" out of them? like this: http://vimeo.com/26362121